# Android cancelling pending intent not working

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am facing this really weird problem. I have made a working alarm system. But when I delete the alarm, it calls it.

AlarmBuddy.java (Working class to set original alarm)

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, m-1);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, d);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, repeat%60);
final Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.context, AlarmMiddle.class);
myIntent.putExtra("name", name);
myIntent.putExtra("id", repeat);
alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

super.onBackPressed();

PendingIntent pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmBuddy.this, repeat, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
  

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pending_intent);
```

ListRecord.java *THE FLAW*

```
public Boolean cancelAlarm(int id){
    Intent myIntent = new Intent();
    PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, myIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT).cancel();
    return false;
}
```

This function is to cancel the alarm. This has some problem to say this again:

The code can SET AND CALL an alarm. But when I delete it from a DIFFERENT class, it immediately calls the alarm. Maybe I am just a noob. Or maybe this is an unsolvable problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for me at all in my application [see link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=developer.nikssoni.schedulesms)

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Your_Service.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getBaseContext(), reqcode, intent, 0);
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Hi @NIKHIL SONI. Thanks, the weird error went away. But the alarm now is not cancelling. HALP!

Answer (score 2):

To cancel the alarm, you need to use the same `PendingIntent` as you used to set it. You should also tell the `AlarmManager` to cancel the alarm as well as canceling the `PendingIntent`. Try this:

```
public Boolean cancelAlarm(int id) {
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmMiddle.class);
    PendingIntent pending_intent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, myIntent,
                     PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    if (pending_intent != null) {
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pending_intent);
        pending_intent.cancel();
    }
    return false;
}
```